# Sparse matrix Constructor doesn't store parameter in object

Tags: c++, class, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix, 2d-vector

I want store a sparse matrix read from a file, but when the constructor finishes the parameters aren't stored in the object.

The file has a "row col" structure, where row is the matrix row and col is the matrix column. If the coordinate of the file exists, it stores a 1 in this position, otherwise it stores a 0.

This is the constructor:

```
MatriuSparse::MatriuSparse(const string nomFitxer) {
        fstream fitxer;
        fitxer.open(nomFitxer);

        int m_columna;
        int m_fila;
        m_Ncolumnes = 8;
        m_Nlinies = 8;
        vector<vector<int> > matriu;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Nlinies; i++)
        {
            vector<int> temporal;
            for (int j = 0; j < m_Ncolumnes; j++) {
                temporal.push_back(0);
            }
            matriu.push_back(temporal);
        }
        fitxer >> m_fila >> m_columna;

        while (!fitxer.eof())
        {
            matriu[m_fila][m_columna] = 1;
            fitxer >> m_fila >> m_columna;
        }
        fitxer.close();
        //Here matrix has size 8
    }
```

And this is the main:

```
 string nomFitxer = "Xarxa1.txt";
    MatriuSparse m1(nomFitxer);
    // Here m1 matrix has size 0
    cout << m1;
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. currently I can't understand what's the matrix format (fields) and how should the matrix be stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor doesn't store anything in the class, except `m_Ncolumnes` and `m_Nlinies` that you set to a constant value.  Everything else is stored in variables that are local to the constructor and that disappear once the constructor is finished.

It is highly probable that you hide a member vector with the same name.  Just remove this line:

```
    vector<vector<int> > matriu;   // hiding the member matriu ?
```

**Not related 1:** you can easily initialize your vector without a nested loop:

```
    matriu = vector<vector<int>>(m_Nlinies, vector<int>(m_Ncolumnes, 0));
```

**Not related 2**: looping on `eof()` doesn't work properly.  You have to loop on the extraction.  So once your matriu initialized, just do:

```
    while (fitxer >> m_fila >> m_columna)
    {
        matriu[m_fila][m_columna] = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you need to make `matriu` a member of the class, not declare it locally in the function.

In addition I have some more comments.

If you know in advance that the size of the matrix is 8x8, it is an overkill to use `vector`, use `array`.

The naming convention is a bit strange. I assume you use `m_` to denote member variables, but `m_columna` and `m_fila` are local variables.

You mention a sparse matrix, but the matrix you are populating `matriu` is in dense format.

Comment: I fully agree on the inconsistent naming convention.  However, the file is a [sparse matrix stored as DOK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Dictionary_of_keys_(DOK))  with a default value of 1 (I guess it's for representing a graph, to say that there is  a connection between node i and j).  Would you agree that the vector approach would be much easier than a 2D array as soon as the size will evolve to a dynamic value ?

Comment: Regarding the container, if the dimension is large or unknown in advance, certainly `vector` is a necessary choice, although I would probably prefer a single vector embedded in a `Matrix` class with an indexing function rather than a vector of vectors. I am not sure however what the use case is here. If the matrix is large, I would normally store it in memory in sparse format and use one of the many matrix libraries which operate directly on sparse matrices. Alternative formats, if it is 0 or 1, could be bitmasks. But it is all speculation anyway, without knowing more on the use case.

Comment: The source (I.e. the file) yes is in sparse format, but the memory storage `matriu` is dense in the posted code.